# C libxml encoding issue.

Tags: c, linux, utf-8, libxml2, biometrics

I'm facing an issue since two days with libxml2 and it annoys me a lot.

Basically, I send a xml buffer throught de network with socket. When I receive it on the server and try to parse it, it says :

> parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
>   Bytes: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF

The one tag of the xml tree (biometricData) I'm trying to send contains weird bizarre caracters cuz this is a raw buffer of crypted data.

```
<biometricData>������������������������

</biometricHeader><biometricData>
                               ^
```

Client side :

```
xmlDocDumpMemoryEnc(doc, &(*out), &buffersize, "UTF-8");
```

Server side:

```
int verify(unsigned char *data, int len) //The routine to check the data and authenticate user.

 xmlParserCtxtPtr ctx_ptr = xmlNewParserCtxt();
 doc = xmlCtxtReadMemory(ctx_ptr, (const char*)data, len, "data.xml", "UTF-8", 0);
```

The server throw this error :

```
Entity: line 2: parser error : Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF 0xFF
d>2.23.42.9.10.4.2</oid></formatOwner></format></biometricHeader><biometricData>
                                                                               ^
```

I try to change to change the encoding to ISO-8859-1 for the server side and it works! But, when I try to do nodeGetContent(biometricData) the data get not in their original encoding, so the buffer is completely useless.

Thank for you taking time. 
I've search towards the xmlCharEncodingHandler but I do not succeed...

Comment: "raw buffer of crypted data" means unencoded binary data? If so encode it with Base64

Comment: Yes that's seems to be raw binary data....

Comment: @robin.koch I've try what you suggested. Well, I'm speechless, You are my hero !!!! Thank you very much. I think without your help I will still be searching the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode all your binary data with base64. XML parsers usually can/will not handle binary data.
I don't know how much binary data you process, so if base64 encoding/decoding becomes inefficient take a look at http://www.xml.com/pub/a/98/07/binary/binary.html

Comment: Base64 is enough for what i'm trying to now.

Thank you once again!

Comment: more on, `0xff` is not a valid utf-8 byte.  This is the reason the library complaints about.